# Parse error PHP file

Tags: php, parsing

I was moving my site and everything is working great except on one page I get the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN in domain/details.php on line 85

It was giving other errors that I manged to fix but this one I can not.

The following is lines 80-85 of the details.php page. Thats the end of the file.
Any help would be great

```
if(!class_exists('Snippets')) {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/snippets.class.php';
    if(!class_exists('Snippets')) {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/snippets.class.php';
}
?>
```

===================

Add new:

Thanks. I treid all the above ways and it still gives error. Now it says line 84(which is last line here). This is what I changed it to:

```
if(!class_exists('Snippets')) {
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/snippets.class.php';

}
?>
```

=========snippets=====

```
<?php
class Snippets {
    function google_analytics() {
        if(ANALYTICS === true) {?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try{
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("<?php echo ANALYTICS_ID; ?>");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}
</script>
<?php }
    }
    function desktop() {
        if(DESKTOP === true) {?>
<p class="bottomlinks"><span>Mobile</span>  |  <span><a href="<?php echo DESKTOP_LINK; ?>">Desktop</a></span></p>
<?php }
    }
    function icon_call() {
        if(CALL === true) {?>
<a href="tel:<?php echo CALL_LINK; ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="images/icon_phone.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="Click to Call" /></a>
<?php }
    }
    function icon_facebook() {
        if(FACEBOOK === true) {?>
<a href="<?php echo FACEBOOK_LINK; ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="images/icon_facebook.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="Facebook" /></a>
<?php }
    }
    function icon_map() {
        if(MAP === true) {?>
<a href="<?php echo MAP_LINK; ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="images/icon_map.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="View a Map" /></a>
<?php }
    }
    function icon_linkedin() {
        if(LINKEDIN === true) {?>
<a href="<?php echo LINKEDIN_LINK; ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="images/icon_linkedin.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="Linked In" /></a>
<?php }
    }
    function icon_twitter() {
        if(TWITTER === true) {?>
<a href="<?php echo TWITTER_LINK; ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="images/icon_twitter.gif" width="38" height="38" alt="Twitter" /></a>
<?php }
    }
    function slogan() {
        if(SLOGAN === true) {?>
<p><?php echo SLOGAN_TEXT_LINE1; ?><br /><?php echo SLOGAN_TEXT_LINE2; ?></p>
<?php }
    }
    function click_to_call() {
        if(CLICKTOCALL === true) {?>
<!-- Start Call Button -->
<div class="buttonclick"><a href="<?php echo BUTTON_LINK; ?>"><?php echo BUTTON_TEXT; ?></a></div>
<!-- End Call Button -->
<?php
        }
    }
}

$snippets = new Snippets;
?>
```

Comment: You need closing bracket after seconf if clause.

Comment: This code is doing the exact same thing twice?

Answer (score 2):

You have two opening `{` and only one closing `}` brace in the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

well you forgot to close the second culry brace.. :) Edit the contenct like this

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/snippets.class.php';
    if(!class_exists('Snippets'))  // Removed the curly brace :)
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/snippets.class.php';
```

Comment: Thanks. I treid all the above ways and it still gives error. Now it says line 84(which is last line here). This is what I changed it to: see above edited:

Answer (score 0):

### You forgot to close a brace !!

```
if(!class_exists('Snippets')) {
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/snippets.class.php';
if(!class_exists('Snippets')) {
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/snippets.class.php';
}
}//<------------ Here
?>
```

Comment: @user3041174, Well, the actual error has gone. Now it seems like you have problem on your `snippets.class.php`. Post the code of it on your question so we can find where's the issue is.

Comment: thanks for the help, new to this. its still saying error on details.php on line 84

Comment: **I asked you to post all the code of snippets.class.php in the question. Just edit the question and add the code of the file so we can have a look**

Comment: Yes. Just posted it. Thank you